# Ember.select selected value

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli and want to select binding value

```
  {{view Ember.Select
      content=industries
      value=industryId         
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

inside route I sutup industries

```
   var industries= [];
    Ember.$.getJSON('/api/v1/Industry',function(items){
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            industries.pushObject({id:item.id,name:item.name});
        });            
    }); 
    controller.set('industries',  industries);
```

I have dynamic model, returns from server, property 'industryId' returns 2, but there always is selected element with id=1

**Update**

```
  {{view Ember.Select
      content=industries   
      value=2   
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      optionLabelPath="content.name"
       }}
```

but is still not selected

Comment: Also $.getJSON will return a promise. So you should handle it with a `.then()` and put the payload push code into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a default "select" option, add the "prompt" property:

```
{{view Ember.Select
      content=industries
      value=industryId         
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      optionLabelPath="content.name"
      prompt="Please Select One"}}
```

Comment: i want to select option by value, which presents in model

Answer (score 0):

If the property industryId is present in the view, then you have to use **view.industryId** instead of just **industryId**.
If it is already present in the controller and you still don't get it, then you use **valueBinding="industryId"** instead of **value=industryId**

Comment: It present in model, which is json from server, I tried mode.indusrtyId ,but  no result.

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kududafu/9/edit here is simple select, as i know 'test 2' must be selected